# Bad encoding in GitLab CI output

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am just learning something about GitLab CI. I have  GitLab Runner running on my local machine successfully connected to my GitLab project. The commands I have written work well but if there is some output in the console with non asci characters, the output in Gitlab shows � characters.

Win10 Pro with Czech localization (corporate machine)

My .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  PROJECT_FOLDER: 'Code'
  PROJECT_NAME: 'Apps.InfoPanels.Cloud.WebApp'

  TEST_FOLDER: 'Apps.InfoPanels.Cloud.Test'
  TEST_NAME: 'Apps.InfoPanels.Cloud.Test'

  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\NuGet\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
  COREBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
  NUNIT_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe'

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - 'tree'

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Debug ".\$env:PROJECT_FOLDER\$env:PROJECT_NAME.sln"'
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
```

And config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "sykora-nb"
  url = "URL"
  token = "TOKEN"
  executor = "shell"
  builds_dir = "C:/GitLab-Runner/builds"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.cache]
```

Is there some magic setting I've missed?

For example I used the *tree* command
[GitLab CI ooutput screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK8hO.png)

Answer (score 10):

Try to add something like

```
before_script:
  - CHCP 65001
```

65001 is UTF-8 encoding

Comment: It is helpful while `cmd` shell is used. But it doesn't work for PowerShell.

Comment: @Alexander, are you sure?  
`PS C:\Users\***> CHCP  
Текущая кодовая страница: 866`  
`PS C:\Users\***> CHCP 65001  
Active code page: 65001`

Comment: I just tried the same fix and it hasn't worked for me either with Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, a resolution for me was switching system language to EN.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the delay. The easiest and the fastest solution in our company was to ask the IT support to create an new virtual server with english version of Widows for running the gitlab runner.